# How to return HH:mm only in date javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm converting seconds to time using this code,

```
var seconds = 8274;
new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
```

And it will return like this `02:17:54`

I need to return only hours and minutes only like this, `02:17`

Please help.

Comment: Just return less charaters: new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 5)

Answer (score 1):

Use the methods getHours() and getMinutes() on the date object like.

```
const d = new Date();
const h = d.getHours();
const m = d.getMinutes();

const t = h + ":" + m;
```

If you want it to be prefixed with a leading 0 when hours or minutes are lower than 10 use the [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using this code `new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let seconds = 11820;

new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString();
 return `'1970-01-01T03:17:00.000Z'`

new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
 return `'03:17:00'`

new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 5);
 return `'03:17'`, which you want :)
```